# Determining if rectangles overlap, if so return the area of overlapping rectangle compare with given set

Tags: c

I am a beginner programmer that is working on elementary tests for myself to grasp core values of working with C. I have a test case and don't really know where to begin in structuring it for compiling with GCC. I have a basic theory and pseudocode summary but mainly needing a little help stepping forward.

I have googled the related questions and permutations to this question and have been unable to make heads or tails of the logic for C.

Given the following logic:

> Using the C language, have the function OverlappingRectangles(strArr)
>   read the strArr parameter being passed which will represent two
>   rectangles on a Cartesian coordinate plane and will contain 8
>   coordinates with the first 4 making up rectangle 1 and the last 4
>   making up rectange 2. It will be in the following format:
>   "(0,0),(2,2),(2,0),(0,2),(1,0),(1,2),(6,0),(6,2)." Your program should
>   determine the area of the space where the two rectangles overlap, and
>   then output the number of times this overlapping region can fit into
>   the first rectangle. For the above example, the overlapping region
>   makes up a rectangle of area 2, and the first rectangle (the first 4
>   coordinates) makes up a rectangle of area 4, so your program should
>   output 2. The coordinates will all be integers. If there's no overlap
>   between the two rectangles return 0.

I'm lost.

Should have added this at first:

1. Given a string(n1,n2,n3,n4,m1,m2,m3,m4)
2. Split string into string1(n1,n2,n3,n4) string2(m1,m2,m3,m4)
3. If n1+n4 < m1 or n2+n3 < m2 or m1+m4 < n1 or m2+m3 < m1
4. Calculate area of intersecting rectangle and divide into area of first rectangle.
5. Else
6. Print 0

Comment: You said you have pseudocode at least. Why not start there and ask a specific question about which part of your pseudocode you're having difficulty with implementing?

Comment: How do `string1(n1, n2, n3, n4)` and `string2(m1, m2, m3, m4)` describe 2 rectangles?  i.e. What do the 4 numbers represent?

Comment: The first problem statement is very difficult, because, when given 4 arbitrary coordinates, they may or may not describe a rectangle.  Furthermore, it allows for the rectangles to be rotated by arbitrary angles, so their intersection need not be a rectangle.  I suspect that the assumption is that the rectangles can be described only by their top-left and bottom-right coordinates.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't clear I figured it was a standard. (X1, Y1, W1, H1)

Comment: Well, it would appear to be the coordinates of the 4 corners of each rectangle, not necessarily in any particular order. You'll need to sort them into some usable order, and give useful names to them. Perhaps end up with the lower left x, y and width and height of each rectangle. Then you need to figure out the geometry of how each rectangle could interact with the other -- no intersection, one enclosing the other, one biting off a rectangle at a corner of the other, one biting off a rectangle in the middle of the other,... etc. Once you have the math, you can code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a string of the form:

```
(x1,y1)(x2,y2)(x2,y1)(x1,y2)(x3,y3)(x4,y4)(x4,y3)(x3,y4)
```

defining 2 rectangles:

```
r1 = (x1,y1) to (x2,y2)
r2 = (x3,y3) to (x4,y4)
```

You need to first:

1. define a representation (structure) for the rectangles
2. parse (read) the string to extract the numbers for `x1`-`x4` and `y1`-`y4` -- look at e.g. `sscanf` and its return value for doing this

You can create a helper function, e.g.:

```
const char *parse_rectangle(const char *str, rectangle *r);
```

That will read a rectangle `r` from `str` in the form `(x1,y1)(x2,y2)(x2,y1)(x1,y2)(x3,y3)` (including any validation) and return a pointer to the next character.

Now, you will have two rectangles.

You can then compute the intersection of these rectangles as a third rectangle, e.g.:

```
int intersection(const rectangle *r1, const rectangle *r2, rectangle *result);
```

which will return `1` if the rectangles intersect, or `0` if they don't and fill `result` with the intersection. If you are using C99, you can use `_Bool` instead.

Now, you need a function to compute the area, e.g.:

```
int area(const rectangle *r);
```

You can pass this through the intersected rectangle and the first rectangle to get the areas of both.

Now, you simply divide the first rectangle area by the intersected rectangle area and print the result.

Comment: Marking this correct as I am sure it will work. Going to thoroughly examine each section and get a solution hashed out. Thank you.